# Wrong redirect when I use declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I migrate my extension to manifest v3.
I need to redirect to page from web_accessible_resources.

I get page:

```
const EXT_PAGE = chrome.runtime.getURL('/test.html');
```

And adding a rule with an action:

```
action: {
    "type": "redirect",
        "redirect": {
        "regexSubstitution": EXT_PAGE + ";\\0"
    }
}
```

String EXT_PAGE = "chrome-extension://.../test.html..."  but after redirect chrome open https://www.chrome-extension//.../test.html... .
It is wrong url.
How I can redirect to exact chrome-extension://.../test.html...?

Comment: It might mean you need to fix your `regexFilter` to not include the result of regexSubstitution. Another problem is that there's no such page: try replacing `;` with `#`.

Comment: I change my rule:
`"regexSubstitution": EXT_PAGE}`

I see variable EXT_PAGE in devtools it is equals `chrome-extension://.../test.html`. And if i open url it will work correct.

After redirect by my rule I see `https://www.chrome-extension//.../test.html` in url. Added `https://www.` and delete `:` before `//`.

why has url changed?

Comment: When I use `"extensionPath": "/test.html"` everything  works okay. But I need to use regexSubstitution because I need to get original url ( '\0' )